# Tomcat URL Routing to specific Class

Tags: java, macos, tomcat7

I have a jsp/java webapp residing in a Tomcat 7 Container on my development environment locally. A production version of the same app is working well. 
The problem with the development site is, that this URL

```
http://localhost:8081/webapp/servlet/serv.Classname?getparam1=1&getparam2=2
```

gives me "the requested resource is not availabel" error, while in production (not my work) it is routed somehow to the correct class file.

How do I accomplish the same behaviour on my local machine, mac os x 10.7, tomcat 7, apache 2?
I've checked all conf/*.xml files in the production tomcat, there is no specific pointing to the behaviour described above. I've checked also rewriting in the httpd also, but nothing.

Where do I have to search to find the configuration in the production version?

Comment: You may have deployed the webapp locally under a different path than production.  Check the tomcat manager to see if the path is the same locally and in production.

Comment: I've installed the production system locally which is a tomcat 5.5 and it worked immediately. This strongly suggest me that the routing is somewhere defined, or the way to point to class files via URL have changed from tomcat5 to tomcat7. The internal paths remained the same in the whole project. The DOMAIN_ROOT variable has changed and I adjusted this variable. Where is the magic happen? Where is defined that this type of URL pattern points to that class file in the application or is this default behavior of tomcat5?